# Determine all linear extensions $\tilde{f}$ of $f$ from $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ or $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ to $\mathbf{R}^{3}$

Tags: functional-analysis

> (a) Let the functional $f$ on $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ be defined by $f(x)=4 \xi_{1}-3 \xi_{2}$, where $x=\left(\xi_{1}, \xi_{2}\right)$. Regard $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ as the subspace of $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ given by $\xi_{3}=0$. Determine all linear extensions $\tilde{f}$ of $f$ from $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbf{R}^{3}$.
> (b) Let $Z \subset \mathbf{R}^{3}$ be the subspace represented by $\xi_{2}=0$ and let $f$ on $Z$ be defined by $f(x)=\left(\xi_{1}-\xi_{3}\right) / 2$. Find a linear extension $\tilde{f}$ of $f$ to $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ such that $\tilde{f}\left(x_{0}\right)=k$ (a given constant), where $x_{0}=(1,1,1)$. Is $\tilde{f}$ unique?

Whenever they say linear extension, do I need to get bounded/norm preserving one or just linear? For $(a)$ I was told to  determine all linear extension, but I couldn't think how to determine that in a general way? Like, we can say $\tilde{f}$ is $f$ whenever $\xi_{3}=0$ and $0$ otherwise.

For $(b)$, I couldn't help me to say something on uniqueness of $\tilde{f}$.

Comment: Hint: a linear map is uniquely determined by the images of some base.  For (a), we have $f(1,0,0)=4$ and $f(0,1,0)=-3$.  Feel free to assign $f(0,0,1)$ to any reell number.  For (b) we know that $$f(1,1,1)=f(1,0,0)+f(0,1,0)+f(0,0,1)=f(0,1,0).$$

Comment: Thanks for your response, @MichaelHoppe. If I understand your word then for $(a)$ we can assign $f(0,0,1)=c\in\mathbb R$. And for $(b)$ we need to assign $f(0,1,0)=k$ (a given constant). But how to write the $\tilde{f}$? In terms of the images of some base.

Comment: It's $\tilde f$ already; it was too late to edit.